# C++ Linked list that loops

Tags: c++, linked-list

Is there any standard C++ implementation of a linked list where the last item points back to the first?  So when you call next on the last element, you go back to the first.  It seems like that would be very useful in gaming, but I don't know of any implementation. thx.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbJaX.png)

Comment: It's a circular linked list.  So, how can you tell you are at the end of the list??????

Comment: What does standard C++ mean? You want to know whether it's in the standard library already? Or you want to know whether you can write your own one in C++?

Comment: [boost::circular_buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Comment: This kind of behaviour should be very easy to emulate using `std::vector` and some basic modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any standard C++ implementation of a linked list where the last item points back to the first?

No. The C++ standard library doesn't have implementation of such data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio implements std::list with a circular type doubly linked list with a dummy node which points to the first and last actual nodes in the list. It is not a true circular list since the first node's previous pointer and the last node's next pointer point to the dummy node (as opposed to each other). In the case of Visual Studio, std::list::end() is an iterator to the dummy node, and so it is a fixed iterator once a list is created. Note that an iterator to the last node can be incremented to std::list::end(), the dummy node, but an iterator to the first node can't be decremented.

You could always create your own class for a true circular single or doubly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily look up which containers are available in the C++ standard library on [**cppreference.com**](https://en.cppreference.com/); specifically, at the [page on containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)...

... and indeed, the standard library doesn't have a circular list implementation.

More generally - the standard library doesn't implement that many containers, and few variants of the same kind of container. You're better off searching popular libraries like Boost, or on GitHub, or even ask for recommendations on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).